# Subtract date-time in Python

Tags: python

I need to calculate difference between time (and if it exceed 24 hours then days)

Like:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import strftime
s1 = '24:11:2014:14:28:42'
s2 = datetime.now().strftime("%d:%m:%Y:%H:%M:%S")
FMT = '%d:%m:%Y:%H:%M:%S'
timedelta = datetime.now.strftime(s2,FMT) - datetime.now.strftime(s1,FMT)
print (timedelta)
```

But this is not detecting more than 24 hours, If found this code which can detect the days:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_format = "%d/%m/%Y %H%M%S"
a = datetime.strptime('22/10/2014 090000', date_format)
b = datetime.strptime('25/11/2014 100000', date_format)
delta = b - a
print (delta.days)
```

What I want is something like this in return: "2 days 03:35:00 HH:MM:SS" in return"

Comment: `datetime.now` is a method. You call it to get a `datetime.datetime` instance. You can *not* call `strftime` on it.

Comment: You are also attempting to subtract **strings**, not datetime objects. That'll not work regardless of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `timedelta` you are getting from `b - a` already has all the information you need, have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.